# Json format MetroLog for windows store app

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I'm using MetroLog framework for my App because i need to send the logs to my backend. 
MetroLog has as target a **JsonPostTarget**

```
conf.AddTarget(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, new JsonPostTarget(1, new Uri("http://localhost:8080/logs/")));
```

The logs are wrapped inside an object and automatically serialized as in json format but not camelCase d. 
So my backend can't deserialize properly the object. 
I can't touch the deserialization for the backend so i need a way to force the camelCase serialization.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't touch the deserialization for the backend so i need a way to force the camelCase serialization.

You could use JSON.NET to serialize the object in camelCase format.

Run the following command to install Newtonsoft Json.NET and using NuGet library

`PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

You can create a `JsonSerializerSetting` to Serialize the object with `JsonConvert` and return the content with content type `application/json`. Then you will get the object in camelCase Json format.

For more details, you might refer to the [blog](http://www.matskarlsson.se/blog/serialize-net-objects-as-camelcase-json) written by @Mats Karlsson.

Comment: Thanks but you don't understood my question